# Почтовый сервер для отправки через php - mail()

Tags: php, email, windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2

Есть сервер (win server 2008 r2), с php 5.5.x, apache 2.4, mysql, nodeJS...
Есть четыре домена, привязанных к ip сервера (соответственно, письма будут отправляться как минимум с 4-х разных ящиков).

Нужно поднять почтовый сервер, который сможет отправлять письма из php скрипта функцией `mail()`. Нужна подробная инструкция о том, как это делать (sendmail, phpMailer и проч. варианты тут не проканают, т.к. доменов несколько и ящиков, а писем в день, возможно, придется отправлять по 10к шт., всяким Яндекс почта для домена и Google это не понравится, если делать рассылку через их сервисы... 
Отсылаться будут письма типа "уведомления о регистрации" и прочие, т.е. не рекламная рассылка).

В общем, как мне быть и что делать?
Благодарен за ваше внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поднимаем почтовый сервер (я не знаю, какие там есть под виндой, не работал) и настраиваем его.
2. В большинство случаев больше ничего не нужно для функции mail(), если почтовый сервер на том же сервере, иначе нужно настроить [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/ru/mail.configuration.php).
3. Настройка DNS записей, там же настройка DKIM и SPF.
4. Профит.

**Обновление**

Проверить можно уже сейчас, отправляет ли mail() письмо. Только искать его придется в 99% в SPAM папке.

По пункту три накидаю ссылок, ибо писать самому лень, и тема заезжена:

- http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2010/10/pochtovyj-server-dlya-nachinayushhix-nastraivaem-dns-zonu.html
- http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2013/10/pochtovyy-server-dlya-nachinayushhih-ptr-i-spf-zapisi-kak-sredstvo-bor-by-so-spamom.html
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/106589/

И в нагрузку https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580

Comment: Например, я установил hMailServer.  
Я уверен, что php mail() сама его не найдет.  
И подробнее, пожалуйста, по пункту 3 о DNS записях.

Comment: Проверить можно уже сейчас, отправляет ли mail() письмо. Только искать его придется в 99% в SPAM папке.

По пункту три накидаю ссылок, ибо писать самому лень, и тема заезжена: 
  
  - http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2010/10/pochtovyj-server-dlya-nachinayushhix-nastraivaem-dns-zonu.html   
  - http://interface31.ru/tech_it/2013/10/pochtovyy-server-dlya-nachinayushhih-ptr-i-spf-zapisi-kak-sredstvo-bor-by-so-spamom.html    
 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/106589/    

И в нагрузку https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580